# Running adb in multiple docker containers

Tags: android, docker, adb, udev

**The problem:**

I have 4 mobile devices connected to USB ports. There are 2 docker containers running in my host machine and each of them has adb daemon running in it. The adb daemon running in the containers picks the devices at random.
I would like to map 2 devices to one container and 2 to the other.

All of my USB devices are listed under `/dev/bus/usb/003/`

This causes both the containers to recognise all the connected devices after the volume is being mounted.

Is there any way in which I can uniquely map a device to a container or make adb detect only certain devices ?

**Solution attempted:**

Mounting individual device to container.

If I mount `/dev/bus/usb/003/001` to a container, adb recognises that device alone. However, once the device is reconnected, the filename changes from 001 to 002 (or any other number) and the container no longer detects it.

Comment: FYI it's possible to run adbd on host and connect adb in container via network to the adbd on host

Comment: Yes. My requirement is to map different devices to different containers. Running adb on host would map all devices to all containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`udev` rule](https://gist.github.com/ktnr74/f749a4bc2aa13b190b46a8643d1b465d) to create a device alias based on the serial number or the specific USB port address and then pass those persistent names to your docker containers.